# Regex for number not starting with 0 and MAX 10 digit

Tags: regex

I am trying a regex for the number which should not start with 0 and can have maximum 10 digits, I tried the following regex but it is not working

```
 1. ^([1-9]+)([0-9]+){1,10}$
 2. ^(([1-9])+([0-9])+{1,10})$
 3. ^([1-9]+)([0-9]*){1,10}$
```

but it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
^[1-9]{1,10}$
```

See a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/dN7qgU/1)

Comment: the number should not start with 0 but can have 0 in it, for instance, this number is valid 1234509, but the above regex will fail in this case

Comment: @LijinDurairaj `^[1-9][0-9]{1,9}$`

Comment: it worked with this ^[1-9][0-9]{0,9}$, thanks @HatLess